# Configurable flag based role permissions in .net

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-authorization

I want to track user roles in a particular way, which seems to me would probably already exist, but I can't find anything on it. I'd like to not recreate this wheel if it exists.

Rather than controller/action based authorization, I want roles to have definable CRUD permissions that I can use to filter out data.

I figure I'd have the CRUD permissions as a simple `Flags enum`:

```
[Flags]
public enum RolePermission
{
    None = 0,
    Create = 1,
    Read = 2,
    Update = 3,
    Delete = 4,
}
```

And then model the roles something like: (using EF Core)

```
public class UserRoles
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public RolePermission Users { get; set; }
    public RolePermission Cars { get; set; }
    public RolePermission OtherUsersCars { get; set; }
    public RolePermission Titles { get; set; }
}
```

Then roll these values into the authentication token as simple key value pairs - UserRoles Id for key, RolePermission for value.

With EF Core I can grab the user claims in the context and do things like filter the response to just "this user's cars" unless they have the `OtherUsersCars` read permission, as one of many examples.

Is there a name for this pattern, or better yet, a specific .net implementation for it that already exists? Everything I'm finding is the "can or can't access controller/action" pattern, which is great, but not what I'm trying to do.